# Grouping of records hour by hour in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, hour

My o/p of the query is like below

```
Date       Hour Orders
2018-02-22 00  22
2018-02-22 03  12
2018-02-22 04  12
2018-02-22 08  12
```

But I want it like this

```
Date       Hour Orders
2018-02-22 00 22
2018-02-22 01 0
2018-02-22 02 0
2018-02-22 03 12
2018-02-22 04 12
2018-02-22 05 0
2018-02-22 06 0
2018-02-22 07 0
2018-02-22 08 12
```

Even though there is no order placed during that hour, that hour should be displayed and it should show order placed as 0.

Comment: Can you show the query? Then we can tell you what to add.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do that is to use oracle "data-densification" method. The key thing is to add partition by clause after outer join like below.

```sql
With Needed_Hours (hr) as ( 
    select lpad(level-1, 2, '0')
    from dual 
    connect by level <= (
        select max(to_number(Hour)) - min(to_number(Hour)) + 1 
        from your_table
    )
)
select t."Date", h.hr hour, nvl(t.orders, 0)orders
from Needed_Hours h
    left join your_table t partition by (t."Date")
        on h.hr = t.hour;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have timestamp data(namely `dt`), split into two columns as date and hour and apply outer join among the data set derived through row generation by difference of extremum hours and the original table(namely `t`) such as

```
WITH t1 AS
(
 SELECT level-1 AS lvl 
   FROM dual 
CONNECT BY level <= ( SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM MAX(dt) - MIN(dt))+1 FROM t )
), t2 AS
(
 SELECT TRUNC(dt) AS "Date", EXTRACT( HOUR FROM dt ) AS hr, orders FROM t
)
SELECT MAX("Date") OVER (ORDER BY lvl ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS "Date", 
       lvl AS "Hour", NVL(orders,0) AS "Orders"
  FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t2.hr = t1.lvl
 ORDER BY t1.lvl
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9bbf157ef8bd1ea9005315c7f355fbf3)</kbd>